# Как эмулировать плавное передвижение курсора по экрану? Pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, поиск-библиотек, pyautogui

Можно ли реализовать (с применением `pyautogui`) плавное передвижение курсора от точки до точки, с неодинаковой скоростью передвижения, с ускорениями примерно как это делает человек мышкой?

Как это лучше сделать?

Есть мысль генерировать список точек определенным алгоритмом а потом двигать курсор по нему.
Справится ли Pyautogui с плавностью?
Или надо поискать другую библиотеку для решения такой задачи?

Comment: Человек не двигает мышью плавно. Можно записать как человек двигает мышью, посчитать статистику (средняя скорость, дисперсия скорости, дисперсия отклонения от маршрута), потом по этим данным сформировать свой маршрут, потом курсор просто двигать по этим точкам.

Comment: Если бы знать как все это считать и вообще что это за слова такие..

Comment: Дисперсия - в статистике условно это степень отклонения всех измеренных значений в последовательности от среднего значения.

Comment: В любом случае для вашей задачи сначала нужно собрать данные как реально человек двигает курсор мыши (потому что он не двигает плавно с плавным ускорением по прямой), проанализировать, посмотреть как меняется скорость, чем лучше аппроксимировать траекторию (прямой или дугой окружности, например), потом на основе этих данных сформировать свою траекторию + добавить некоторое случайное отклонение на основе посчитанной дисперсии (есть функции, которые позволяют превратить равномерное распределение случайных чисел в нормальное распределение - приближенное к реальности).

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за пояснения. А можно названия подобных функций озвучить? Возможно мне не не понадобится очень точно эмулировать пока что как человек двигает курсором. Попробую порешать задачу от обратного, кстати часто так делаю.

Comment: Для сбора данных можно хоть tkinter взять, в окне периодически показывать кружок, в который должен ткнуть пользователь, траекторию перемещения мыши записывать. Для обработки данных наверное удобно numpy будет взять, хотя можно просто и циклами списки обрабатывать. Конкретные функции не назову, с numpy мало работал, а так вычисление дисперсии можно и вручную реализовать, там не такая уж сложная формула.